# Rails tests not running because of FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to run my tests.

The problem is that my database is not getting cleaned before running the tests (I am not sure if it is supposed to be automatically cleaned up).

I am running my tests with:

```
rspec spec
```

This is the error:

```
 `save!': Validation failed: Name has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

And this is the factory that fails:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do 
    email "user@example2.com" 
    first_name "Myname"
    last_name "MyLast name"
    password "DoeDoe12" 
    api_license FactoryGirl.create(:api_license)
  end 
end
```

This is my spec_helper

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'factory_girl_rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  #config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"


end
```

That is the right approach on this scenario?

Comment: How many users do you create with FactoryGirl?  If more than one, you need to make sure that the relevant attributes are unique.  Look at FactoryGirl's `sequence` method.

Comment: Just one, I think. That's my entire users factory

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of your test database? If it doesn't have any users defined, then please share your spec.

Comment: Can you post your spec_helper.rb file?

Comment: I have just posted my spec_helper.

Comment: Do you have any tests that fail in addition to the one failing when a user name is already taken?  It's not unusual for a failed test to leave the (failed) data in the DB and then have subsequent tests trip over it.

Comment: Try using [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner)